# which spatio-temporal properties does dynamic textures exhibits?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, text-recognition, photo

know that dynamic textures are spatially repetitive and temporally varying patterns.

1.I read one sentence in one paper **i.e. They are sequences of frames exhibiting certain stationarity properties over time. They exhibit spatial self-similarity and temporal self-similarity.** but i don't understand how it does?

2.**Also how examples like "traffic on road" or "rafting" can be considered as Dynamic Textures**? Because i don't thing they exhibit any stationarity property over time.is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stationarity over time just means that if you come back and look at the traffic sometime later it will look pretty much the same as it did when you first saw it. Sure there will be different cars but even the new cars will look similar to the first ones. The cars might be in different positions but their random arrangement will have the same properties as the original arrangement.